# Any reason to upgrade to EF 4.1+ if using database first?

Tags: .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, entity-framework-4.1

I am using EF 4.0 (System.Data.Entity included in .NET 4.0) "database first" and am wondering whether there is any reason for me to upgrade to EF 4.1 or higher. EF 4.1+, available via NuGet, appear to be oriented towards "model first" only, but I am not sure whether any "database first" bug fixes or features have gone into these new releases.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the DBContext API. It is also useful when using database first. Basically it wraps the ObjectContext API and provides an easier interface, but it is still possible to access the inner object context API if you want to. The DbContext code generation item also produces nice clean code.

Answer (score 0):

I used 4.3 code first on a small project to work with existing db. I don't like mapping existing db to code with model cause i'd like to full control classes and ef code first allows to write minimim possible code for mapping. Also it's nice to use external file mapping(no attributes mapping to have complete POCO) is separate classes (not partial).